# match for a character if previously the other character is found

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to match c style comments in one regex. For ex

```
int i /* ABC 123 */
int i // ABC 123
```

What I could write is

```
(.*?)(?:/\\*|//)\\s*(ABC)\\s*(\\d)+\\s*
```

This matches only

```
int i /* ABC 123 
or
int i // ABC 123
```

Is there a way in regex I tell if I have /* in my string then */ should be there and if it starts with // i should not match  for */

If it is possible then what is the regex for the same.

/* */ is used as multi line comment in C but in my case it might not be multi line. as I gave in the example -> int i /* ABC 123 */ is just one line.

int i /* ABC 123 */ and int i // ABC 123 both are same in C. So I wan't to write a regex that matches both the line in one regex if I encounter them one after the other.

Comment: Are you saying you want to do multi-line searches as well?

Comment: This is a task for a parser, not regex.

Comment: It seems that you've forgotten to put `\*\/` at the tail of the regex to match entire comment string.

Comment: Nope I didn't forget. If I put \\*/ at the tail of regex then with that regex I can't match line int i // ABC 123 because my regex expects */ at the end. If I make */ as optional then it matches line like int i /* ABC 123 which I don't want. So I want to have a \\*/ with the condition if my line had a character /* somewhere before */.

Comment: Why not branch the two cases like this `(.*?)(?:/\\*\\s*(ABC)\\s*(\\d)+\\s*\\*/|//\\s*(ABC)\\s*(\\d)+\\s*)`?
Or you want the capture `(\\d)` to match in both (comment-style) cases? I think it's possible but to try working out it is a waste of time and it'll be too complicated to maintain it.

Comment: I thought there could be some simple solution for this which I don't know with a single regex. So asked. If it is difficult then I would go with separating it out as you mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but I'm going to assume that:

1. You're matching multiple lines
2. You're matching line by line

If not, then you could probably modify this answer to work.

---

I think the easiest way to do this is to set a boolean variable `isInMultiLineComment`. If you find  an opening comment (`/*`) without a closing one (`*/`), then this will be true, and the other type of comment (`//`) should be ignored.

You can do something similar with a variable `isInSingleLineComment`.

Comment: I have edited my question. I don't want to match multi line comment but match single line with multi line comment syntax. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String regex = "//(.*)|/\\*(.*?)\\*/";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(yourString);
while (matcher.find()) {
   // print/add to list whatever you want
   // matcher.group(1) refers to the content of comment //
   // matcher.group(2) refers to the content of comment /* */
}
```

Expalantion

```
//       Simply matches //
   (.*)  Group 1 matching anything
|         OR
/        Matches / from /*
\\*      Matches * from /*
(.*?)    Group 2 matching anything till the first
\\*      * is found
/        Match a /
```